# Jsoup library "Did not find balanced marker" error

Tags: java, groovy, jsoup, katalon-studio

Using `jsoup` library I am trying to get the `href` of an `<a>` element which contains specified text each time.

Example:

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document
import org.jsoup.select.Elements

public class GlobVars {
    public static Document currentPageSource
    public static String currentTitle
}

def get_url() {
    String url = "https://www.website.com/"
    GlobVars.currentPageSource = Jsoup.connect(url).get()

    Elements wElements = GlobVars.currentPageSource.select('a[class="class-name"]:contains('+GlobVars.currentTitle+')')
    if(wElements) {
        /*
         * Do stuff...
         * 
         * */
    }
}
```

The problem is when `GlobVars.currentTitle` contains single quote character!!! For example, if `GlobVars.currentTitle` is `I am here` it "works" fine. But if `GlobVars.currentTitle` is `I'm here` i get this error: `Did not find balanced marker at 'I'`.

I tried to use `GlobVars.currentTitle` variable with `double-quoted`, `triple-single-quoted` or `triple-double-quoted` but I get the same error.

I also read https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/issues/1105 but the "[trick](https://try.jsoup.org/%7EtQywDLPdfB0IPT9FFNb5Z7JnjWI)" to escape quotes can not be used in my case.

Any idea how I'll fix this?

Comment: @TDG As I wrote, if the text of `<a>` element contains single quote character I get this error. In any other case it's okay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
// @Grab(group='org.jsoup', module='jsoup', version='1.14.3')

import org.jsoup.Jsoup
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document
import org.jsoup.select.Elements

def html = """
<html>
<body>
<a class="c1" href="#1">i'm the one</a>
<a class="c1" href="#2">i am the one</a>
</body>
</html>
"""

def desiredText = "i'm the one"
// escape special chars. maybe you need more special chars to escape...
desiredText = desiredText.replaceAll(/(['"\\\/\|(\)\[\]])/, '\\\\$1') 

Document currentPageSource = Jsoup.parse(html)
Elements wElements = currentPageSource.select('a[class="c1"]:contains('+ desiredText +')')
```

or

```js
def desiredText = "i'm the one"
Elements wElements = currentPageSource.select('a[class="c1"]').findAll{it.html().contains(desiredText)}
```

Comment: What is this `it` at second case???

Comment: It's a default variable name 
for closure (unnamed function) with one parameter. You could name param: `.findAll{x-> x.html().contains(desiredText) }`

Comment: findAll: https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#findAll(groovy.lang.Closure)

Comment: I don't know it looks correct but it doesn't work for me... I update my code can you take a look please?

Comment: i've updated the answer, but without html sample and desired text that is not working - i can't help more